# Angular Analytics Splunk Logging

Tags: angularjs, logging, google-analytics, splunk, web-statistics

I have an angular page that I've developed for my co. that I want to track the usage statistics for. Just very basic information like number of hits. I am trying to use the angulartics plugin found [here](http://angulartics.github.io/#/getting-started). So far this is what I have in my angular page that I copied from the git examples folder:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Topic Tester</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="static/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/angulartics.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/angulartics-splunk.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sp=sp||[];
        (function(){var e=["init","identify","track","trackLink","pageview"], t=function(e){return function(){sp.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};
            for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++)sp[e[n]]=t(e[n])})(), sp.load=function(e,o){sp._endpoint=e;
            if(o){sp.init(o)};
            var t=document.createElement("script");
            t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0,t.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"d21ey8j28ejz92.cloudfront.net/analytics/v1/sp.min.js";
            var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n)};

        sp.load("http://localhost:9000/api/log");
    </script>
</head>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['angulartics', 
                                    'angulartics.splunk']);
```

Of course the script in the html needs adjusting because of the endpoint but I have a problem there. The way my co. has splunk logging setup is this:
Developer does any kind of logging they want in the java app. All the logging goes to `catalina.out`. Application gets deployed to various remote servers (Dev, QA, Prod). Developer can run a search query in enterprise splunk hosted on company domain to search in a particular box (dev box) for a particular log file (`tomcat.log`, `catalina.out`, etc).

In this scenario, how would I make the angular app log to a file (doesn't have to be `catalina.out` obv since splunk can query for any log file) whereby splunk will be able to pick it up from its deployment box?

If that's not possible, do I need to put some splunk endpoint in the `sp.load` line whereby the angular page will send it's stats directly to splunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

If you want to log to a file like the Java apps your company uses, you'll need to create a backend service that your Angular app can send data to. That backend service can then write to a file.

If you're running Splunk 6.3 or newer, you can use the [HTTP Event Collector](http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAE6M) to send events over HTTP with better performance all around. You can use our [Splunk logging for JavaScript](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-javascript-logging) library with [browserify](http://browserify.org/), see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-javascript-logging/issues/4) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a more plug & play Angular (1.5) solution based on angular-loggly-logger that might be easier to use: https://github.com/mer10z/angular-splunk-logger

It uses $http to post to the Splunk HTTP Event Collector so you don't need browserify or any other external dependencies.